# Talking Navigation for taxi drivers flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, waze

Building a flutter/dart taxi driver/rider app and looking to help drivers with turn by turn talking navigation for drivers to be taken to the pick up and destination address, are there any products like waze, google maps that are supported in flutter/dart thnks

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you want help with? Based on your explanation you want to just embed existing solutions into Flutter.

Comment: I would recommend this package: https://github.com/eopeter/flutter_mapbox_navigation. It has step by step navigation for Flutter. It does not use Waze or Google Maps though.

Comment: Taxi driver would be abl eto hear the turn by turn instruction show to get to pick up and destination and passenger would see the taxi coming towards her/him.